# How the best way to realize math.pow on btn click?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me?
I stack at 60 line
I do not know how better implement this method

May be need keep all data in array?
and through regular expressions pull out what I need

```js
 function set(num) {
   document.getElementById("calcAll").innerText += num;
 }

 function operator(e) {
   var expression = document.getElementById("calcAll").innerText,
     result = document.getElementById("result"),
     calcAll = document.getElementById("calcAll");

   switch (e) {
     case "c":
       calcAll.innerText = '';
       result.innerText = '';
       break;
     case "=":
       try {
         result.innerText = eval(expression);
         calcAll.innerText = expression + '=' + eval(expression);
       } catch (e) {
         alert('неа');
       }
       break;
     case "+/-":
       calcAll.innerText = expression * -1;
       break;
     case "xy":
       //
       //
       //
       //
       result.innerText = Math.pow(x, y);
       calcAll.innerText = Math.pow(x, y);
       //
       //
       //
       //
       break;
   }
 }
```

```css
.screen {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#result {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id="calcAll"></div>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="operator('=')">=</button>
<button onclick="set(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="set(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="set(3)">3</button>
<button onclick="set(4)">4</button>
<button onclick="set(5)">5</button>
<button onclick="set(6)">6</button>
<button onclick="set(7)">7</button>
<button onclick="set(8)">8</button>
<button onclick="set(9)">9</button>
<button onclick="set(0)">0</button>

<div>
  <button onclick="operator('c')">C</button>
  <button onclick="set('%')">%</button>
  <button onclick="set('-')">-</button>
  <button onclick="set('+')">+</button>
  <button onclick="set('/')">/</button>
  <button onclick="set('*')">x</button>
  <button onclick="set('.')">.</button>
  <button onclick="operator('+/-')">+/-</button>
  <button class="red" onclick="operator('xy')">xy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve], and [edit] your question accordingly. We cannot help you if we don't understand what the issue is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, obviously it's a calculator; it seems to run fine in the code snippet. We just need a better explanation of what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got exactly what you want, but i guess you want know how to calculate pow, right?

I tried to do in the same way you did other pieces.

### javascript code:

```js
function set(num) {
   document.getElementById("calcAll").innerText += num;
 }

 function operator(e) {
   var expression = document.getElementById("calcAll").innerText,
     result = document.getElementById("result"),
     calcAll = document.getElementById("calcAll");

   switch (e) {
     case "c":
       calcAll.innerText = '';
       result.innerText = '';
       break;
     case "=":
       try {
         
         if (expression.indexOf("xy") > -1) {
           var arrExp = expression.split("xy");
           var num1 = eval(arrExp[0]);
           var num2 = eval(arrExp[1]);
           
           result.innerText = Math.pow(arrExp[0], arrExp[1]);
           calcAll.innerText = expression + '=' + Math.pow(arrExp[0], arrExp[1]);
         } else {
           result.innerText = eval(expression);
           calcAll.innerText = expression + '=' + eval(expression);  
         }
         
       } catch (e) {
         alert('неа');
       }
       break;
     case "+/-":
       calcAll.innerText = expression * -1;
       break;
     case "xy":
       //
       //
       //
       //
       result.innerText = Math.pow(x, y);
       calcAll.innerText = Math.pow(x, y);
       //
       //
       //
       //
       break;
   }
 }
```

```css
.screen {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#result {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="screen">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id="calcAll"></div>
</div>

<br>


<button onclick="operator('=')">=</button>
<button onclick="set(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="set(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="set(3)">3</button>
<button onclick="set(4)">4</button>
<button onclick="set(5)">5</button>
<button onclick="set(6)">6</button>
<button onclick="set(7)">7</button>
<button onclick="set(8)">8</button>
<button onclick="set(9)">9</button>
<button onclick="set(0)">0</button>

<div>
  <button onclick="operator('c')">C</button>
  <button onclick="set('%')">%</button>
  <button onclick="set('-')">-</button>
  <button onclick="set('+')">+</button>
  <button onclick="set('/')">/</button>
  <button onclick="set('*')">x</button>
  <button onclick="set('.')">.</button>
  <button onclick="operator('+/-')">+/-</button>
  <button class="red" onclick="set('xy')">xy</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See here: https://jsbin.com/cabilehuvi/edit?js,console,output

**For example: click on 3, and after on xy, and after on 2, and after equals. You'll get 9.**

Comment: tnx. <br>
u sat that "I tried to do in the same way"<br>
and how would you do it?

Comment: I used xy as a operator like +, - and others. I split when i have a xy, because u can't eval xy because it doesn't exists, so, when you have a expression before XY and other after it calculates. I put it on "equals"

Comment: yes thank you, I realized, but u sat that "I tried to do in the same way".
I know what I wrote is not the best way) and I would like to know how can make calculator another way, or how could it be improved?

Comment: well, you can do it in many many many ways... I think asa good start you can read about javascript design patterns, unobstrutive javascript and others for code.